# How can I choose the destination of the generated .jasper file into Jaspersoft Studio 6.1?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am absolutly new in **JasperReports** and I have the following problem: I am woking on a project that generate an Excel file into **Jaspersoft Studio 6.1.0**.

After that I save my **.jrxml** file project and build it, so it seems that it generate the related **.jasper** file into the **Desktop** folder of my Windows system.

How can I choose the directory into wich generate this **.jasper** file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not as in [ireport](/questions/tagged/ireport) choose where the .jasper is build.

[Quoting](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/821471/changing-compile-directory-jasper-studio) mrabbi (jasper report staff)

> currently in Jaspersoft Studio when compiled the JRXML produces the
>   `.jasper` file in the **same folder** position where they are. This is an
>   implementation choice.

You can hide them if you don't like to see them and you can configure an "additional" output directory on build (`jasper` will be copied to this).

[image: Configure output folder]

Answer (score 1):

In IReport it was Tools > Options > IReport > Compilation and Execution then untick "Use Report Directory to compile" and you could select a new one.

[image]